# Everything works fine when install from android studio and same results when i install from playstore except one activity with PDF is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, google-play

Application is working fine when i install from android studio but when i install it from playstore one activity and one Fragment are having problems and these both fragment uses a common PDF file. That activity/Fragments shows a PDF book in a PDFViewer but on loading that activity application crashes.

**CompleteBookFragment.java**

```
public class CompleteBookFragment extends Fragment {
private static int defaultPageNumber = 0;
private PDFView pdfView;

public CompleteBookFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().setTitle("مکمل کتاب");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_complete_book, container, false);
    final ProgressBar bar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarCBF);
    bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    pdfView = view.findViewById(R.id.complete_book_pdf);
    pdfView.fromAsset("book.pdf")
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .defaultPage(defaultPageNumber)
            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .enableDoubletap(true)
            .onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                    bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                })
               .load();
          return view;
    }

    }
```

**BookReaderFromIndex.java**

```
public class BookReaderFromIndex extends AppCompatActivity {

public BookReaderFromIndex() {
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_reader_from_index);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(HelperFunctions.getTypeFacedSpannableString(this, "کتاب"));
    final ProgressBar bar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarBRFI);
    bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int defaultPageNumber = intent.getIntExtra("pageNumber", 0);
    PDFView bookReaderFromIndex = findViewById(R.id.bookReaderFromIndex);
    bookReaderFromIndex
            .fromAsset("book.pdf")
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .defaultPage(defaultPageNumber)
            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .enableDoubletap(true)
            .onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                    bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            })
            .load();
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

As it only throws error when install from playstore so the logcat looks like this

```
2019-11-26 12:03:20.216 23677-23939/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:475] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN 
APPLICATION: java_class == null
2019-11-26 12:03:20.216 23677-23939/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:475]     in call to 
GetMethodID
2019-11-26 12:03:20.216 23677-23939/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:475]     from c.f.a.b.a 
com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.nativeGetPageSizeByIndex(long, int, int)
2019-11-26 12:03:20.216 23677-23939/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:475] "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 
tid=17 Runnable
2019-11-26 12:03:20.216 23677-23939/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:475]   | group="main" 
sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12dc34c0 self=0x7f5891e000
```

**and**

```
 2019-11-26 12:03:21.889 23947-23947/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.geekybugs.nifliibadat, PID: 23947
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.geekybugs.nifliibadat/com.geekybugs.nifliibadat.Activities.MainActivity}: 
 androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$d: Unable to instantiate fragment c.c.a.c.b: could not find Fragment 
constructor
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
 Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$d: Unable to instantiate fragment c.c.a.c.b: could not find Fragment constructor
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.a()
    at b.k.a.e.a()
    at b.k.a.j$c.a(:2)
    at b.k.a.j.a(:192)
    at b.k.a.d.onCreate(:3)
    at b.b.k.m.onCreate()
    at com.geekybugs.nifliibadat.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate()
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1683)
```

Comment: Is it printing the Title properly? getActivity().setTitle("مکمل کتاب"); try changing this title to make sure language is not the issue

Comment: @VinayJayaram yes it is printing it and no its not the issue i checked, my app have other fragments and activities with same language and they are working fine

Comment: what is the name of your app in playstore?

Comment: This is the playstore link to the application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geekybugs.nifliibadat
and thank you for your time and response.

Comment: Are you using proguard? Make sure to keep PDF classes when signed APK is built.

Comment: @Hussain yes i am using proguard, i am just a beginner so  what do you exactly mean by "Keep PDF Classes"

Comment: In `proguard-rules.pro` file define the class you don't want proguard to remove from APK. Check [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/practical-proguard-rules-examples-5640a3907dc9) and [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) for reference.

Comment: Thank you @Hussain it fixed the problem, proguard was the culprit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using barteksc/AndroidPDFViewer to load PDF files and i was also using proguard and proguard was creating this problem as Highlighted by the @Hussain in the comments section and this issue was also addressed on the github [Issue](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/480).

So it was solved when i added

```
-keep class com.shockwave.**
-keepclassmembers class com.shockwave.** { *; }
```

in the proguard-rules.pro

All thanks to Hussain.